# Error in Keras when I want to calculate the Sensitivity and Specificity

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, metrics

I am writing a code for classification between two types of images based on a CNN.
I want to measure the accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity for my work but unfortunately, I have the following error. 
Could you please let me know what my problem is.

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.SensitivityAtSpecificity(0.5)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy',m])
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hamed/PycharmProjects/Deep Learning/CNN.py", line 77, in <module>
    validation_steps = 1600//batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\Hamed\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hamed\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\Hamed\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 217, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\Hamed\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1217, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "C:\Users\Hamed\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Hamed\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "C:\Users\Hamed\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Hamed\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Resource localhost/false_negatives/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
     [[{{node metrics/sensitivity_at_specificity/AssignAddVariableOp_1}}]]
     [[{{node metrics/sensitivity_at_specificity/Mean}}]]
```

Answer (score 4):

The metric tf.keras.metrics.SensitivityAtSpecificity calculates sensitivity at a given specificity [Click here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/SensitivityAtSpecificity).

Unfortunately sensitivity and specificity metrics are not yet included in Keras, so you have to write your own custom metric as is specified [here](https://keras.io/metrics/).

The following is one simple way to calculate specificity found at [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33587/keras-custom-loss-function-as-true-negatives-by-true-negatives-plus-false-posit/40746#40746).

```
def specificity(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    param:
    y_pred - Predicted labels
    y_true - True labels 
    Returns:
    Specificity score
    """
    neg_y_true = 1 - y_true
    neg_y_pred = 1 - y_pred
    fp = K.sum(neg_y_true * y_pred)
    tn = K.sum(neg_y_true * neg_y_pred)
    specificity = tn / (tn + fp + K.epsilon())
    return specificity
```

You can get Keras implementations for specificity and sensitivity on [this link](http://www.deepideas.net/unbalanced-classes-machine-learning/).

Answer (score 1):

You Can try this, if it helps...

```
import keras

model.compile(optimizer="adam",
              loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=[keras.metrics.Precision(), keras.metrics.Recall(), keras.metrics.SpecificityAtSensitivity(0.5), keras.metrics.SensitivityAtSpecificity(0.5), 'accuracy'])
```